# Entity Framework Core can't infer type from generic

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been trying to implement a generic repository and I have found that Entity Framework Core can't infer types from generics and I think I might forced to do extension method with typed entities, is it not possible to use generics on Join with Linq?

```cs
public  async Task<IEnumerable<V>> Join<V, T, VID, TID>(this EntityRepository<T> repositoryEntity,
        Func<T, TID> joinIdEntity, Func<V, VID> joinIdEntity1,Func<V, T, V> join)
            where T : class, new()
            where V : class, new()
    {
        Db.Set<T>()
          .Join(Db.Set<V>(), joinIdEntity, joinIdEntity1, join);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the VID and TID generic parameter. According the Join method signature the join key must be of the same type. Since joinIdEntity is of type `Func<T,TID> joinIdEntity` and JoinIdEntity1 is of type `Func<V, VID>` no join is possible. The only solution is to declare the method as following:

```
public  async Task<IEnumerable<V>> Join<V, T,VID>(this EntityRepository<T> repositoryEntity,Expression<Func<T,VID>> joinIdEntity, Expression<Func<V, VID>> joinIdEntity1,Func<V,T,V> join)
        where T : class, new()
        where V : class, new()
    {

        return Db.Set<T>().Join(Db.Set<V>(), joinIdEntity, joinIdEntity1, (e,v) => v);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `Expression<Func<>>`? Looks like this repository pattern will kill SQL server quickly.

Comment: Yes, that would be another improvement. But I just copy paste the method signature from the question owner

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtual props in your model so you don't have to use join EF Core will get everything for you if you set correctly your model with annotations

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was conflicting with the T entity generic on the class so the correct way to write it would be

```
 public async Task<ICollection<TResult>> Join<VEntity, TKey, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> outerKeySelector, Expression<Func<VEntity, TKey>> innerKeySelector, Expression<Func<T, VEntity, TResult>> resultSelector) 

        where VEntity : class ,new()
        where TResult : class,new()
    {
        try
        {
            return await Db.Set<T>().Join(Db.Set<VEntity>(), outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector).ToListAsync(); ;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```